# Cloudformation Split & ImportValue

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, aws-cloudformation

I have 2 stacks in CloudFormation. One is creating a vpc with a couple of subnets which are exported in order to be used in other stacks. The idea is to have those subnets to be used in other stacks.
The vpc stack exports the values properly but I am unable to Import them in the second stack because it uses a list of strings.

Stack 1:

```
  PrivateSubnets:
    Description: "A list of the public subnets"
    Value: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref PrivateSubnet1, !Ref PrivateSubnet2 ]]
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${StagingArea}-PrivateSubnets"
  
  PublicSubnet1:
    Description: "Reference to the publi subnet in the 1st Availability Zone"
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PublicSubnet2: 
    Description: "A reference to the public subnet in the 2nd Availability Zone"
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Description: "A reference to the private subnet in the 1st Availability Zone"
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet1
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${StagingArea}-PrivateSubnet1"
  PrivateSubnet2: 
    Description: "A reference to the private subnet in the 2nd Availability Zone"
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet2
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${StagingArea}-PrivateSubnet2"
```

When I try to ImportValue into my second stack it does not work. Stack 2 below:

```
  DbSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: !Sub "${StagingArea} RDS DB Subnet Group"
      SubnetIds: 
        - !ImportValue 'Fn::Sub': '{$StagingArea}-PrivateSubnet1'
        - !ImportValue 'Fn::Sub': '{$StagingArea}-PrivateSubnet2'
```

Is it possible to get the values exported from the first stack into the second stack? I have tried various options but none of them seem to be working.

Comment: I noticed that you have some questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good good practice, but also helps others and eliminate duplicates. If all the answers were not helpful, that's fine, but if you are not accepting helpful answers, ppl may skip your questions  in future.

Comment: @Marcin, sorry about that. I believe I put 2 questions in the past that I also replied back myself with the solution for the problem. I will keep that in mind the future though.

Comment: How did it go with `ImportValue` and the current issue?

Comment: It works fine now, replied to your answer with the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sub` is **incorrect** (wrong use of `$`) and its better to follow the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) and have the statement in two lines:

```
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub '${StagingArea}-PrivateSubnet1'
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub '${StagingArea}--PrivateSubnet2'
```

Comment: you were right, it was my mistake when adding the $ sign. It works now with the lines that you added above. Many thanks for your answer and comment earlier regarding accepting correct answers.